# A question about cofinal totally ordered sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $A$ be an uncountable set, and let $L$ be the poset consisting of all finite subsets of $A$ (the ordering on $L$ is inclusion). Show that $L$ does not have a totally ordered cofinal subset.

I am not really sure about the best way to go at this. I am not sure how to deal with uncountable sets; this is new to me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $C$ is linearly ordered and cofinal in $L$.

- Show that since $C$ is cofinal in $L$, it must be uncountable.
- Show that there is some $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that uncountably many members of $C$ have cardinality $n$.
- Derive a contradiction.

Comment: There's really no need for contradiction here. Pick a linearly ordered set, show it's countable, conclude that its union is countable, therefore it's not cofinal.

Comment: @Asaf: But the easiest way to show that it’s countable is by contradiction.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18391/discussion-on-answer-by-brian-m-scott-a-question-about-cofinal-totally-ordered").